# Export content to MS Word and Import content from MS Word from CKEditor using PHP

Tags: php, ckeditor

I am building an application in PHP for a news paper agency here in India. Using this application reporters form various location can post their reports (NEWS or Features). These reports after getting the aproval from Chief Editor is send to the press for printing. To help these reporters with their daily task my application uses a CKEditor, using this editor reportes can post their reports in the system.

Now I want to build a functionality (with PHP and CKEditor) using which reporters can import formated content from MS Word into CKEditor,  work on the imported content in CKEditor and once done they can export the modified content to MS Word form CKEditor.

It will be very helpful if anyone can guide me as to how I can implement this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

i have similar problem
the only way i found is to use Gembox.Document ($500) which converts html into word (very nice).
please tell me if you have found another and maybe free solution. Thanks!